# What the hell is this part that fell off my car?

Tags: toyota, part-identification, volvo, sienna, xc60

I rotated my tires today and heard something fall from the front-end of the car somewhere while I was jacking up the car. I didn't think anything of it until I was sweeping up after and found this metal snap ring. Because I found it after and wasn't paying attention, I'm not even 100% sure which car it fell from! It could've been from either a 2013 Volvo XC60 (non-turbo) or a 2013 Toyota Sienna XLE 3.5L. Does anyone know what this thing is?

[image: snap ring]

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update: it was from the jack! The shaft in the picture was being held on by one snap ring on each side. Since posting the question, I found another one just like the first. I am hoping they were just not secured correctly and now that I've popped both of them back in, I'm good.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

What it is is a snap ring. I have no clue where it would have fallen off of, so your guess is as good as mine. Snap rings are usually enclosed within places, like to hold bearings in place. It would not have fallen off due to rotating your tires alone.

**EDIT:** Looking closer at the image you provided, it looks to me to be an *unused snap ring*. I see no evidence of any type of wear on it or tool marks where you'd normally see them if it's been put in place somewhere for use.

Comment: It's definitely a snap ring, this one's shape means it's designed to go on the outside of something, not the inside as the lobes stick out.